# Move root partition to beginning of free drive space with gparted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

My file system is split into / and /home partitions (currently /sda/sda5 and sda/sda6), and my home partition is almost out of space. I want to use GParted in order to move the root partition to the beginning of the 4gb of free space, along with the /home partition so the free space is at the end of my drive. However, GParted isn't allowing me to move my root partition. 


I've gone through the other questions here but I can't really understand it/I can but it won't work.

My drive layout is below:

[my drive layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw7Tj.png)

[The option to move it to the left just isn't there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5RST.png)

Would it be better to just use one partition for the root and /home drives? 
 

If so, how would I do that. 


Please know that I'm not very proficient at using linux, and certainly not at GParted, and although I don't mind complex answers I would prefer ones as simple as possible (Also please go through it step by step if possible)


Thank you

Comment: The "beginning of the drive" is occupied by /dev/sda1, an ntfs partition. What do you intend to do with it? Also, why bother?

Comment: Your drive is effectively full. Windows is over full as it wants 30% free to work at 10% you may not have room to defrag. Unless erasing Windows you have no real space to gain.

Comment: Although agreeing with the previous comments, I must add you can move *sda5* and *sda6* to the left and then extend each or one of them in order to use the now unallocated space. Your strategy of having a separated /home makes sense but the assigned space for / and /home doesn't.  / can be small as it is for OS and programs only whereas /home is the primary location for the users' personal files which are potentially big if we're talking about HD movies and stuff.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'd love to be able to move sda 5/6 to the left but for some reason I can't do it... there isn't a left arrow allowing me to move it there :/

Comment: You must use live installer's gparted, not from inside your install. You can only move unmounted partitions and you cannot unmount your working / (root). Moving start of / partition may require reinstall of grub of other fixes, so just be prepared with live installer and Boot-Repair or know manual commands to reinstall grub.